# Returning proper type after using OrderBy()

Tags: c#, linq, generics, casting

I have a collection class that inherits from `List<>`. I've set up a function to sort the list by a certain property like so:

```
public PlaylistCollection SortByName(IEnumerable<Playlist> playlists)
{
    return (PlaylistCollection)playlists.OrderBy(p => p.Name);
}
```

When I try to use the sorted results in my code like this:

```
artistSource.Playlists = (PlaylistCollection)new List<Playlist>(artistSource.Playlists.SortByName(artistSource.Playlists));
```

I get the error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[...Playlist,System.String]'
 to type '...PlaylistCollection'."
```

This is moderately frustrating considering VS told me that an explicit conversion exists, so I added the above cast.

How do I properly cast from `IEnumerable<>` to my collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to know what the right answer is without understanding more about the type PlayListCollection.  But assuming it's a standard style collection class which has a constructor taking an IEnumerable<T>, then the following code should do the trick.

Extension Method

```
public IEnumerable<Playlist> SortByName(IEnumerable<Playlist> playlists)
{
    return playlists.OrderBy(p => p.Name);
}
```

Use of Method

```
var temp = artistSource.Playlists.SortByName(artistSource.Playlists);
artistSource.PlayList = new PlaystListCollection(temp);
```

If not, please post more information about PlayListCollection, in particular the constructor and implemented interfaces, and we should be able to help you out with your problem.

**EDIT**

If the above code does not work you can use the following extension method to create an instance of the PlaylistCollection class.

```
public static PlaylistCollection ToPlaylistCollection(this IEnumerable<Playlist> enumerable) {
  var list = new PlaylistCollection();
  foreach ( var item in enumerable ) {
    list.Add(item);
  }
  return list;
}
```

Comment: While I had tried your first suggestion before already, I combined it with your second suggestion and it worked just fine. I'd have done it like that initially, I was just hoping for a more 'elegant' solution, I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're looking less for how to cast the result and more how to stuff it into a `List<>`.  I was looking for a simple way to do the same thing and found the following solution:

```
artistSource.PlayList = playlists.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList<PlayList>();
```

The `ToList` extension method is available in .NET 3.5. The following links contain additional information:

[Enumerable.ToList Method (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.90%29)

[Sorting a List<FileInfo> by creation date C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001544/sorting-a-listfileinfo-by-creation-date-c-sharp)