# Sorting a List<FileInfo> by creation date C#

Tags: c#, sorting, dataview

Using this example off MSDN:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.IO;  

namespace CollectionTest  
{  
    public class ListSort  
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();  
            files.Add(new FileInfo("d(1)"));  
            files.Add(new FileInfo("d"));              
            files.Add(new FileInfo("d(2)"));  

            files.Sort(new CompareFileInfoEntries());  
        }           

    }  

    public class CompareFileInfoEntries : IComparer<FileInfo> 
    {  
        public int Compare(FileInfo f1, FileInfo f2)  
        {  
            return (string.Compare(f1.Name, f2.Name));  
        }  
    }  

}
```

How would I compare the date of creation.

F1 has a property "creation" date which is a FileSystemInfo.Datetime, yet when I try this:

```
  public class CompareFileInfoEntries : IComparer<FileInfo>
  {
      public int Compare(FileInfo f1, FileInfo f2)
      {

          return (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(f1.CreationTime), f2.CreationTime));
      }
  }  
}
```

I get overload method matches for `String. compare(string,string)` 
Note: Ive used two methods in the above script to attempt returning the creation time. Neither have worked - they would both be the same in my actual script.

CLosest I can get is:

```
return (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(f1.CreationTime.ToString()), DateTime.Parse(f2.CreationTime.ToString() )));
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Description

You can simple use `LINQ (namespace System.Linq)` for that.

> **Language Integrated Query (LINQ, pronounced "link")** is a Microsoft .NET Framework component that adds native data querying capabilities to .NET languages

#### Sample

```
List<FileInfo> orderedList = files.OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime).ToList();
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)
- [Wikipedia - Language Integrated Query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_integrated_query)

Comment: Damn. Forgot I could use LINQ. One downside of using intellisense when you haven't called the LINQ namespace! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Umm what about using linq

```
files.OrderBy(f=>f.CreationTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim filePath as string = "c:\\"
```

This command get directory file list ordered by ASC

```
Dim orderedFiles = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(filePath).GetFiles("*.xml")
                                                        .OrderBy(Function(x) x.CreationTime)
```

This command get directory file list ordered by DESC

```
Dim orderedFiles = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(filePath).GetFiles("*.xml")
                                                        .OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.CreationTime)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
public class CompareFileInfoEntries : IComparer<FileInfo> 
    { 
        public int Compare(FileInfo f1, FileInfo f2) 
        {
            return (string.Compare(f1.CreationTime.ToString(), f2.CreationTime.ToString())); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: That is almost guaranteed to fail to work properly, though it might *purely accidentally* work on some Cultures.

Comment: @Barber - Even if the cultures changes, both of the fileinfo creation time will be changed against that culture and if both of them are changed accordingly then it should work fine.. I am confused !!!

Comment: In en-us, the date would outpit like this: *1/28/2012 12:28:30pm* compared to *5/15/1972 5:34:10pm* The sorting would be *wrong*. You are converting to a string which does *not* sort the same way as a date.